# SQL Server: Left Join Select Statement gets an error "The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization"

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create a View table that will contain 2000+ columns, and 95% of the declared properties in the select statement are also select statement sub-queries.

This is what I'm trying to do:
table A = main table with 100 columns
table C = sub table with 10 columns

table C is gonna join table A. But instead of 100 columns from A + 10 columns from C, it's gonna be 100 columns from A + (10*every row in the table that has fk = pk which is up to 200) from C.

Here is my sample code:

```
select
A.*
, 

(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 1 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property1,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 2 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property2,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 3 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property3,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 4 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property4,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 5 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property5,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 6 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property6,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 7 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property7,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 8 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property8,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 9 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property9,
(select C.property where C.propertyNumber = 10 and C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk) as property10

from [schema].table A
left join [schema].table C on A.propertyIdPk = C.propertyFk
where C.propertyFk = A.propertyIdPk
```

Is there another way to do this or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: To understand better, are you joining the columns in table A to the rows in table C?

Comment: PLEASE GROUP BY WITH ALL FIELDS OF TABLE A.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it really sounds like you need to reconsider your schema design. I've seen this error before when people had too many FKs in place, but always, that gets back to schema design issues.